How to modify javascript to have the table start sorted on a certain column on page load
I have looked at other questions like this but I am so unused to javascript that I cannot understand how to integrate their solutions into my code. I need someone to look at mine and tell me what to do. Thank you.
This javascript came from a pre-built table made to be more accessible for assistive technology. I would love for the table to start sorted A-Z on the first column (Products). Here is the code:
https://codepen.io/The-Alberta-Library/pen/zYVyroJ
Thanks again.
The javascript:
/*
 *   This content is licensed according to the W3C Software License at
 *   https://www.w3.org/Consortium/Legal/2015/copyright-software-and-document
 *
 *   File:   sortable-table.js
 *
 *   Desc:   Adds sorting to a HTML data table that implements ARIA Authoring Practices
 */

'use strict';

class SortableTable {
  constructor(tableNode) {
    this.tableNode = tableNode;

    this.columnHeaders = tableNode.querySelectorAll('thead th');

    this.sortColumns = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < this.columnHeaders.length; i++) {
      var ch = this.columnHeaders[i];
      var buttonNode = ch.querySelector('button');
      if (buttonNode) {
        this.sortColumns.push(i);
        buttonNode.setAttribute('data-column-index', i);
        buttonNode.addEventListener('click', this.handleClick.bind(this));
      }
    }

    this.optionCheckbox = document.querySelector(
      'input[type="checkbox"][value="show-unsorted-icon"]'
    );

    if (this.optionCheckbox) {
      this.optionCheckbox.addEventListener(
        'change',
        this.handleOptionChange.bind(this)
      );
      if (this.optionCheckbox.checked) {
        this.tableNode.classList.add('show-unsorted-icon');
      }
    }
  }

  setColumnHeaderSort(columnIndex) {
    if (typeof columnIndex === 'string') {
      columnIndex = parseInt(columnIndex);
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < this.columnHeaders.length; i++) {
      var ch = this.columnHeaders[i];
      var buttonNode = ch.querySelector('button');
      if (i === columnIndex) {
        var value = ch.getAttribute('aria-sort');
        if (value === 'descending') {
          ch.setAttribute('aria-sort', 'ascending');
          this.sortColumn(
            columnIndex,
            'ascending',
            ch.classList.contains('num')
          );
        } else {
          ch.setAttribute('aria-sort', 'descending');
          this.sortColumn(
            columnIndex,
            'descending',
            ch.classList.contains('num')
          );
        }
      } else {
        if (ch.hasAttribute('aria-sort') && buttonNode) {
          ch.removeAttribute('aria-sort');
        }
      }
    }
  }

  sortColumn(columnIndex, sortValue, isNumber) {
    function compareValues(a, b) {
      if (sortValue === 'ascending') {
        if (a.value === b.value) {
          return 0;
        } else {
          if (isNumber) {
            return a.value - b.value;
          } else {
            return a.value < b.value ? -1 : 1;
          }
        }
      } else {
        if (a.value === b.value) {
          return 0;
        } else {
          if (isNumber) {
            return b.value - a.value;
          } else {
            return a.value > b.value ? -1 : 1;
          }
        }
      }
    }

    if (typeof isNumber !== 'boolean') {
      isNumber = false;
    }

    var tbodyNode = this.tableNode.querySelector('tbody');
    var rowNodes = [];
    var dataCells = [];

    var rowNode = tbodyNode.firstElementChild;

    var index = 0;
    while (rowNode) {
      rowNodes.push(rowNode);
      var rowCells = rowNode.querySelectorAll('th, td');
      var dataCell = rowCells[columnIndex];

      var data = {};
      data.index = index;
      data.value = dataCell.textContent.toLowerCase().trim();
      if (isNumber) {
        data.value = parseFloat(data.value);
      }
      dataCells.push(data);
      rowNode = rowNode.nextElementSibling;
      index += 1;
    }

    dataCells.sort(compareValues);

    // remove rows
    while (tbodyNode.firstChild) {
      tbodyNode.removeChild(tbodyNode.lastChild);
    }

    // add sorted rows
    for (var i = 0; i < dataCells.length; i += 1) {
      tbodyNode.appendChild(rowNodes[dataCells[i].index]);
    }
  }

  /* EVENT HANDLERS */

  handleClick(event) {
    var tgt = event.currentTarget;
    this.setColumnHeaderSort(tgt.getAttribute('data-column-index'));
  }

  handleOptionChange(event) {
    var tgt = event.currentTarget;

    if (tgt.checked) {
      this.tableNode.classList.add('show-unsorted-icon');
    } else {
      this.tableNode.classList.remove('show-unsorted-icon');
    }
  }
}

// Initialize sortable table buttons
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
  var sortableTables = document.querySelectorAll('table.sortable');
  for (var i = 0; i < sortableTables.length; i++) {
    new SortableTable(sortableTables[i]);
  }
});


I have looked at a lot of other threads on how to start tables sorted on a certain column at page load, but none of them make sense to me because I know nothing at all about javascript and cannot understand how to integrate their solutions, especially since none of them are working on code that is optimized for assistive technology.

that package hasn't seen any commits in the last 9 years. are you sure this is the tool you want to use?

Can't you simply sort the data when you're creating the table in the first place? That seems to be how the codepen was created, since it starts out sorted.

@Barmar it's not sorted by first column ascending with the header triangle pointing upwards

Right, I didn't examine the last 2 rows carefully, they're out of order.

This is just a fraction of the entire table. My student got bored and alphabetized the first chunk by hand. It's not feasible to do that for the rest of the table, as well its going to change over time. I wish it was that simple though.

You can follow the handler that runs when a click on the header. By examining the code and testing, this works:
// Initialize sortable table buttons
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
  var sortableTables = document.querySelectorAll('table.sortable');
  for (var i = 0; i < sortableTables.length; i++) {
    var instance = new SortableTable(sortableTables[i]);
    instance.sortColumn(0, 'ascending')
  }
});

Update: This won't change the sorting triangle.
But if the library doesn't support this, any solution might be hacky like faking a click or adding classes to elements. The next code will work, but you didn't get it from me...
// Initialize sortable table buttons
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
  var sortableTables = document.querySelectorAll('table.sortable');
  for (var i = 0; i < sortableTables.length; i++) {
    var instance = new SortableTable(sortableTables[i]);
    instance.setColumnHeaderSort(0)
    instance.setColumnHeaderSort(0)
  }
});


I really appreciate you trying to help. Thank you. I commented out what was already there under "// Initialize sortable table buttons" and added in your options but neither of them seem to work.

Never mind! Classic user error. It works! Thank you so much.
